# survey_details does not contain all the question_id's

Tags: surveymonkey

I've put out a survey and gotten >100 responses. However, when I get the survey details using the api (i'm using python if it helps), then get the responses from respondents, I find a question in the response that is not present in the survey details.

I thought that the responses would only have question id's that were present in the survey details -- so I'm not sure what is going on.

Any help/advice?

Comment: Is it a deleted question that someone answered?  If so that's expected behavior.  It's a known issue, but AFAIK no fix has been made yet.

Comment: This help article might help you confirm that there are deleted questions on the survey in question: http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Can-I-restore-a-deleted-question-in-the-survey-design

Comment: There have been no deleted questions in the last 14 days, and even if they were deleted, I believe the responses are going to be purged as well.

Comment: you can only get 100 at the time iirc. You need to request the second page.